# How to find an element by text and click on it using puppeteer js

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, click, puppeteer

I want to find a specific element that contains text and click on it.
There is an element like:
`<a class="name" href="/main/photo/qwweqqeqwe"> This text </a>`
There are many elements of the `class="name"`, and I need to click on the element that will contain certain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const [element] = await page.$x('//a[text()="More information..."]');
    // For partial match:
    // const [element] = await page.$x('//a[contains(text(), "More")]');
    await element.click();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow find an element using only one word, if, for example, this element consists of two?

Comment: See the comment in the code about partial match: `const [element] = await page.$x('//a[contains(text(), "More")]');`